# Random graphics corruptions

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card

I've recently gotten some graphics corruptions, and they've been getting more common recently. For instance, as I'm writing this, I have this one in chrome (the barcode-like thing at the top right):

[image: Corrupted stuff]

At first I thought this was a Chrome thing, but I started seeing this in other applications. Making the application do a redraw fixes the problem, but after some time, another one pops out somewhere else.

Sometimes it's barcode-like black-and-white structures, sometimes they're colored, but they're always in rectangular blocks.

I'm guessing these may be caused by problems in VRAM, so for now I'll change the video card. I don't think it's a RAM problem, because if it got randomly corrupted, I'd be getting bluescreens, and so far I've gotten none.

My setup is an HP Z420 Workstation

- CPU: Xeon E5-1620 3.6GHz
- Southbridge: Intel X79
- Memory: 2GB x8 (seems to be mixed between Micron and Hyundai)
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 550 Ti 1GHz
- OS: Windows 7 Professional SP1

I'm doing no overclocking or other strange stuff

Any ideas?

Comment: doesnt look like any video card gpu or video card ram problem that I have ever seen. Unless it is something new areo specific, or chrome running in a "3D accelerated" mode is doing.  If it is some 3D thing, try adjusting the antialising, and anisotropic, as in try and shut most of the 3D feature sets off when using that program (a 3d profile via the card software)  Or just find out how to shut off chrome from running in the 3D accelerated mode.

Comment: @Psycogeek it's not just Chrome. I've also seen that on many other programs including PuTTY, Skype, Notepad, Visual Studio 2012. I think it's a systemwide problem, not just related to Chrome. I changed the graphics card and so far I've seen no problems.